# Inclusion of C headers in C++ revisited

Tags: c++, c, header-files, extern

I just read [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile) discussing scenarios in which a piece of code is valid in both C and C++ but would produce different behavior in each language.

This begs the question: **Could this ever be a problem when including C headers in C++ code?**

I know [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329159/including-c-headers-inside-a-c-program) that you should include C headers like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <your_os_or_library_header_in_c.h>
}
```

But all I found so far is that the extern "C" only guarantees that *name mangling* is turned off.

I couldn't find any information on whether it evaluates *all statements* as C, so that e.g. `sizeof('a')` or `10 //* comment */ 2` (which you could find in an inline function) are parsed as C and not C++. (Note that relying on such behavior as someone who writes a C header is obviously a bad idea, but I'm asking it from a purely academic standpoint of "What if?".)

**Does the C++ standard say that enclosing a block of code in `extern "C"` means that *all* statements in it must be parsed as C?**

Comment: Either way, if the C header declared a symbol called e.g. `new`, this would fail to compile in C++.

Answer (score 7):

`extern "C"` is a C++ construct which affects language linkage in a C++ program. It does not switch the language to C in any way. All source text inside an `extern "C"` declaration is still parsed as C++ and as C++ only.

Note that `extern "C"` affects more than just name mangling - it is (theoretically) possible that functions with C and C++ language linkage could have different calling conventions, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I should maybe add the question: "Is this ever going to be a problem in the Real World™?" Or would any sane developer of an OS or library header strictly avoid such problems and make sure the *header itself* produces the same behavior in both C and C++?

Answer (score 3):

`extern "C"` only changes linking, i.e. mangling and possibly the calling convention. Try compiling and running this program with both a C and a C++ compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    inline void putsizeofchar()
    {
        printf("%zd\n", sizeof(char));
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main()
{
    putsizeofchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Since header inclusion is textual substitution in both languages, the lack of a header doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thank you. I should maybe add the question: "Is this ever going to be a problem in the Real World™?" Or would any sane developer of an OS or library header strictly avoid such problems and make sure it produces the same behavior in both C and C++?

Comment: @AlecBender: no developer in their right mind writes programs that are both C and C++ at the same time. Instead, they pick either language for the implementation, then use `extern "C"` to make sure it has an API for the other one.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I wasn't talking about writing *programs* that are both C and C++ at the same time, but writing the *headers* for their interface in a way that produces the documented behavior in both C and C++ (ie no inline functions that do what you did in your example.)

Comment: @AlecBender: I put inline functions in a lot of my C++ headers :) But if you want C/C++ interop via a header, then make sure the header is pure C except for the `extern "C"` and include it in the C++ modules that implement it to make sure they get compiled the right way.