# cmake can't build simple project

Tags: c, cmake

I'm use clion 1.0 with cmake and try to build simple demo project. But cmake don't want link external .c file to main.c.

System: Xubuntu 14.04

main.c

```
#include "common/source_file.h"

void SetupRC()
{
    Cmake_dermo(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetupRC();

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(mytest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(mytest common/source_file.h common/source_file.c ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

source_file.c

```
#include "source_file.h"

void Cmake_dermo(int da)
{
    da += 1;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What error message you got? (Add it to you question post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you `CMakeList.txt` and i got

> In function SetupRC():
>   main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to Cmake_dermo(int)

The problem comes from the fact that different languages are mixed:

- main.cpp is C++ and the compiler is a C++ compiler.
- source_file.c is C, since it is a .c file.

To include a header featuring reference to C, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329159/including-c-headers-inside-a-c-program). A corrected main.cpp file looks like:

```
extern "C"
{
  #include "common/source_file.h"
}

void SetupRC()
{
  Cmake_dermo(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SetupRC();

  return 0;
}
```

The header file looks like:

```
#ifndef SOURCE_FILE_H_   /* Include guard */
#define SOURCE_FILE_H_

void Cmake_dermo(int da);

#endif // SOURCE_FILE_H_
```

It seems that Cmake takes care of the different languages without any modification to the CMakeList.txt.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong filename in your CMakeLists.txt file.

Change the line in your CMakeLists.txt from:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
```

to:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
```

Comment: Right...It could be a typo in the CMakeList.txt as well !