# extern "C" causing an error "expected '(' before string constant"

Tags: c++, c, extern

file1.c

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return (a+b);
}
```

file2.cpp

```
void main()
{
    int c;

    c = add(1,2);
}
```

h1.h

```
extern "C"  {

#include "stdio.h"

int add(int a,int b);
}
```

Case 1:
when i include **h1.h** in **file1.c** file then gcc compiler throw an error "*expected '(' before string constant*".

case 2:
when I include **h1.h** in **file2.cpp** file compilation work successfully

Question:

1) Does it mean that I can not include header file in C with extern "C" function in it??

2) Can I include header within extern"C" like shown below

```
extern "C" {

#include "abc.h"
#include "...h"
}
```

3) Can I put c++ functions definitions in header file with extern "C" so that i can call it in C file?

for example

a.cpp  ( cpp file)

```
void test()
{
   std::printf("this is a test function");
}
```

a.h (header file)

```
extern "C" {
void test();
}
```

b_c.c  ( c file)

```
#include "a.h"

void main()
{
  test();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329159/including-c-headers-inside-a-c-program

Comment: `extern "C"` is a C++ feature: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage

Answer (score 12):

Write a.h like this:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

int add(int a,int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This way you can declare multiple functions - there is no need to prefix each one with extern C. 
As others mentioned: extern C is a C++ thing, so it needs to "disappear" when seen by C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Since extern "C" is not understood by a C-compiler you need to create a header that can both be included in a C and C++ file.

E.g.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" int foo(int,int);
#else
int foo(int,int);
#endif
```