# How to use some Unix header file in a C++ source file?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I plan to use some Linux API to finish a network program task in C++ language. All the Linux API or structure are defined in the C header file, such as `<netinet/in.h>`, How to use them correctly in Cpp source file? How to use a struct defined in C header file?
Should I use C++ linkage specification? such as:

```
    extern "C" {
        #include <netinet/in.h>
};
```

Comment: C++ is mostly backward compatible to C. Is there any issues?

Comment: In C language, when I have to use a struct to define an object,  I have to put the "struct " keyword before the struct name, but in CPP, we don't have to do that.

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't do that.

Comment: OK, you mean , In C++, if we want to use a structure defined in C, we still have to put the "struct" keyword before the structure name? Is there some better choice?

Comment: ... Again, _is there any issues_? Why can't you just assume the header is written in C++ and proceed normally?

Comment: `extern "C"` is for linking other programs to yours, not yours to others. And as @user202729 keeps saying, you don't need to worry about that anyways. Simply `#include <netinet/in.h>` then when you need a `sockaddr_in` structure, simply `sockaddr_in sock_obj;` or `sockaddr_in* sock_obj = new sockaddr_in();`.

Comment: @user202729 you can't because C and C++ are different languages,  C allows things that are not allowed in C++ linyuwang gave one example above,  another difference is the list of reserved words.

Comment: @Jasen _C allows things that are not allowed in C++_ .. prey tell?

Comment: Ok, use `extern "C"` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3329159/5267751). Because it's C++ anyway (outside of the `extern "C"` block) you don't need the `struct`. **Just try it before asking**.

Comment: `void this(void) {;} // not allowed in c++`

Comment: Or `int new;`. But it's unrelated here.

Comment: @Jasen .. that's not a valid example of something not allowed. Keywords are keywords.

Comment: voting to close as "cannot reproduce issue".

Comment: @user202729 Even if C grammar is equivalent to C++ grammar, `extern C` must be used because of ABI incompatibilities. The first that comes to my mind is name mangling. Inside an object file, a function `int f(int)` will be named `f` if it has C linkage and `_Z1fi` if it has C++ linkage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system headers in `Linux` are already `C++` compatible, you don't need to do anything other than `#include` them. In fact the vast majority of `C` libraries have `C++` compatible headers so you just `#include` them without issue.

There are some exceptions (like `ffmpeg`). Those you need to wrap with `extern "C" {}`. Although it may not always be possible to use a native `C` header simply by wrapping it in that way because `C` can contain other incompatibilities.

See here for an example using [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Including%20FFmpeg%20headers%20in%20a%20C%2B%2B%20application)

Comment: For the detail, those libraries that are C++ compatible use conditionnaly defined preprocessor macros so that when included in a C++ translation unit, all their content is inclosed in `extern "C"`. For example `sys/cdefs.h` file defines `__BEGIN_DECLS extern "C"{` if compiled inside a C++ TU, which is then used in hundreds of other headers.